# in Android API 23 - why can I not programmatically alter ringtones?

Tags: java, android, ringtone, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to programmatically change a ringtone in API 23.

I have looked at a lot of examples on Stack Overflow and they all seem to "work" (i.e. not crash) but they do not "work" as in the mp3 doesn't become the ringtone - instead the ringtone becomes simply zero noise. So obviously /something/ happened. (no crash, now no ringtone noise)

I have split this off into a small side project to try to isolate it because it's driving me up the wall - I hope maybe you guys can see something I can't!

I have:

- placed the mp3 in \res\raw
- I have verified I can play the mp3 fine with this code

  ```
  MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(me, R.raw.meepmeep);
  mPlayer.start();
  ```
- added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>` to the manifest
- managed the api 22 permission scenario in java

  ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .setMessage("Please Assign Meep Meep Write Permissions")
              .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                      intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                      try {
                          startActivity(intent);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          Log.e("MainActivity", "error starting permission intent", e);
                      }
                  }
              })
              .show();
      return;
  }
  ```

  - used a method to carefully fetch the mp3 path from the assets folder

    ```
    public String LoadFile(String fileName, boolean loadFromRawFolder) throws IOException
    {
      InputStream iS;

      if (loadFromRawFolder)
      {
        int rID = resources.getIdentifier("meep.example.com.meep:raw/"+fileName, null, null);
        iS = resources.openRawResource(rID);
      }
      else
      {
        iS = resources.getAssets().open(fileName);
      }

      byte[] buffer = new byte[iS.available()];
      iS.read(buffer);
      ByteArrayOutputStream oS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      oS.write(buffer);
      oS.close();
      iS.close();

      return oS.toString();
    }
    ```
- tried to carefully copy the file to the local storage (as a desperate attempt to get it to work as well as tried to assign it from the raw assets lib

  ```
      String path = "";
      try {
          LoadFile("meepmeep", true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          //display an error toast message
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(me, "File: not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.show();
      }

      //copy file to device
      File newSoundFile = new File(path);
      //Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://meep.example.com.meep/R.raw.meepmeep");
      Uri mUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
      ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
      AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
      try {
          soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
          try {
              byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
              FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
              int i = fis.read(readData);

              while (i != -1) {
                  fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                  i = fis.read(readData);
              }

              fos.close();
          } catch (IOException io) {

          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          soundFile=null;
      }

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Meep Meep");
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "RoadRunner");
      //values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
      values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

      //Insert it into the database
      Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
      Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

      try {
          RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                  me,
                  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                  newUri
          );
      }
      catch (Throwable t){
          setMessage("meepmeep error");
      }
      setMessage("meepmeep set");
  }
  ```

but nothing seems to work. It always fails becuase either `soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");` returns null or if I decline to use that code block and try to change ringtone direct from `\res\raw\` folder then it simply gives a blank sound for ringtone.

I am totally stuck for ideas?

Comment: Error logs please!

Comment: either null exception - the line `soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");` returns null, or if I take the code block out an just start at `values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());` then all I get is no error but a zero sound ringtone

Comment: hmm, I think issue is related to permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>, doesn't work in 23, hope you know that.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work but the UAC privilege elevation via the AlertDialog does work - and i employ it programmatically